# Docker : how to read configmap & secret in asp.net core application?

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, configmap

I am Dockerizing the Asp.net core application and how do I read configmap & secret in asp.net core application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing an app for Kubernetes, you should usually follow the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) guidelines.

It is common that the app read config-values as Environment variables, but sometimes also as files. The Kubernetes documentation has good examples on how to use [ConfigMaps for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#configmaps-and-pods) to read the values as Env variables or files.